# How do use regex to find match multiple matches for one attribute?

Tags: regex

I have a table with entries that have attribute names like "3000." Some entries have one number for each attribute, but some entries have multiple numbers for some attributes. For example, one entry could have a value "ABC" and "DEF" for an attribute called 3000.

I want to find any values associated with the attribute called 3000, and there are three values ... ABC, DEF and GHI. When I pull all of the attribute information, I can see the multiple values for an entry called 0-001:

```
... ^3000:ABC, ^3000:DEF, ^3000:GHI ...
```

I'm using the following expression, but it only returns the *first* entry, but not the rest.

```
(attribute_list, "\\^3000:([^\\^]*),")" from myTable where entry_id="0-0001"
```

It returns only the value "ABC," but I want it to return "ABC," "DEF," and "GHI." What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try it out tomorrow when I get back in the office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all your attributes:

```
(?<=\^3000:)[^,\s]+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wJ3xM7).

Output: `ABC`, `DEF`, `GHI`

If you also want to return the `^3000`, then use this regex:

```
\^3000:[^,\s]+
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=\^3000:)` asserts that what precedes is `^3000:`
- The negated character class `[^,\s]+` matches one or more chars that are neither a comma nor a whitespace character

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sB4fR4).

---

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well your regular expression wouldn't match the `3rd` value in your data because there is no comma that follows it, there is only a space character. I would use negation with a comma or space character here.

```
\\^3000:([^, ]+)
```

This will find all matches but if it doesn't work for you then you need to do a global search in your SQL call.